# Record data of dynamically changing table in same web page

Tags: datatable

There is web site, which has table. Table has some pages and by choosing the certain page, table returns some data. So i need to record these all data from all pages of table in same page. Help to solve this problem! 
the web site: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/dn602597.aspx
Below you can see the table. Help me retrieve(parse) these all data by using javascript, java, php or something else.

Comment: Have you checked whether the table is loaded dynamically or not?

Comment: @CurtisJ.Malainey, no! i can't understand how to record data! because when i reload the whole page, where table is located, it gives the same result!

Comment: Inspect the page and look at all the web requests made, I bet they are using REST, find that URL and load the JSON and you are done.

Comment: @CurtisJ.Malainey How I can find this URL??? I have searched, but I couldn't find URL

Comment: You need to do some more research on REST requests and parsing HTML/JSON before you come back here.